# Return on complete async with RxJs

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to return a value (a string), from a function which calls an API using rxjs. The variable has to be returned in the complete clause of the observable.

This is the code:

```
getToken(): any {
    let token = '';

    this.meService.getMe().subscribe(data => {},
      err => {
        let headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8').set(InterceptorSkipHeader, '');
        this.http.post(Configs.heroku + 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token', 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=' + localStorage.getItem('refresh') + '&client_id=' + Configs.appId + '&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/redirect&' + 'client_secret=lkcqTNT730}zyoVLOX45)|;', {headers: headers}).subscribe(data => {
          localStorage.setItem('access', data['access_token']);
          token = localStorage.getItem('access');
        });
      },
      () => {
        return localStorage.getItem('access');
      });
  }
```

As you can see: I'm trying to return a variable in the complete clause. However, it never returns a variable. When I print it out in the calling function, it just says undefined. Any solutions?

Thanks in advance!

edit:

This is the part where the function gets called:

```
console.log(auth.getToken());
    req = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth.getToken()
      }
    });
```

Comment: Return it to what, exactly? Your outer method doesn't return anything.

Comment: Yeah well, I want to return from my "complete clause". As you can see, there's a return there.

Comment: Yes, I can see that, but it's unclear where you expect that to go. Return *to what*?

Comment: I edited my question. I expect 'auth.getToken()' to return the value as specified in the return statement.

Comment: You have not understood how async (RxJs/Promise) JavaScript programming works.

Comment: First of all note that it cannot return synchronously. You need to return an observable. Secondly note that you shouldn't be subscribing in the method if you plan to return an observable.

Comment: If I return an observable. It means that I have to copy the body in the (err -> { //body }) to every call right? I don't want to do that...

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36342784/angular-2-return-data-from-rxjs-subscribe. Note that you can use e.g. `.catch` to centralise some error handling.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm an Angular noob. I really don't see the bigger picture in that question. I have 2 calls inside my subscribe.

Answer (score -1):

I'll try to explain you what is happening.

1. Your getToken function is not returning anything. So you get undefined when print it out.
2. When you subscribe an observable, you have 3 possible arguments:

   - next: It is executed every time you get a "tick" in your observable.
   - error: It is executed when it gets an error.
   - complete: It is executed when the observable is completed.

In any of these cases you are passing a callback that must be executed when each of these events happens. Since you are returning inside of these calbacks, you are not returning the getToken method, but the function that is called inside the subscribe method. Imagine a possible implementation of the subscribe method:

```
subscribe(nextCB, errorCB, completeCB){
    ...
    if(completed) {
        completeCB();
    }
}
```

As you can see, the value you are returning for complete callback is not being assigned or returned.
You have multiple solutions/alternatives for your case. You can return the observable itself (this.meService.getMe()) with some maps and then subscribe it wherever you want to or you can simply run your code inside the complete callback. 
But IMO it is better to spend some time looking for javascript general closure and async concepts.